# in which type of project I could add the java program for apache solr with eclipse?

Tags: solr

I am going to use apache solr for first time. I just want to write a basic code for apache solr in java with eclipse. Can you please suggest me that how to get familiar with apache solr.

Comment: Solr is a document search server. You do not need to use a specific project type _for solr_. You use Solr from the kind of project you're writing (i.e. webapp/console tool, etc.), not the other way around. You can follow [the tutorial in Solr's reference manual](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/solr-tutorial.html), or seek out one of the many resources for how to use SolrJ - Solr's own Java library for interfacing with Solr over HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, SOLR is a full text search engine. You can use it as a data store to keep data of unstructured nature. You can use SolrJ to communicate to SOLR from Java.